# Auto-merging package-lock.json

Tags: git, github, gitlab

```
git merge --no-ff account-creation
```

Auto-merging package-lock.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in package-lock.json
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Any idea regarding this issue ?

Comment: delete package-lock.json then run merge again

Comment: @DaveCarruthers Bad idea as that bumps all dependencies to the most current version which may lead to a broken project. Rather, check which changes were done in the package.json on each branch and reapply  them.

Comment: @DaveCarruthers The whole idea of a lockfile is to be able to trust that the dependencies are in a known-to-work state. While your approach might work in small projects (or for `package.json` that have already very fixed semvar range), it may fail legacy projects having a large dependency tree. I try upgrading all the dependencies, yet I have projects where I can only manually update one dependency at a time which may also lead to dev-overhead0

Comment: @k0pernikus - You responded to Dave as though he suggested deleting package-lock.json and then running `npm i` again, but he didn't. He suggested running merge again. Why would that bump all dependencies to the most current version? Wouldn't that just make sure the current branch has the same package-lock.json as the incoming branch?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-locks#resolving-lockfile-conflicts):

> #### Resolving lockfile conflicts
>
> Occasionally, two separate npm install will create package locks that
> cause merge conflicts in source control systems. As of `npm@5.7.0`,
> these conflicts can be resolved by manually fixing any `package.json`
> conflicts, and then running `npm install [--package-lock-only]` again.
> npm will automatically resolve any conflicts for you and write a
> merged package lock that includes all the dependencies from both
> branches in a reasonable tree. If `--package-lock-only` is provided,
> it will do this without also modifying your local `node_modules/`.
>
> To make this process seamless on git, consider installing
> [`npm-merge-driver`](https://npm.im/npm-merge-driver), which will
> teach git how to do this itself without any user interaction. In
> short: `$ npx npm-merge-driver install -g` will let you do this, and
> even works with pre-`npm@5.7.0` versions of npm 5, albeit a bit more
> noisily. Note that if `package.json` itself conflicts, you will have
> to resolve that by hand and run `npm install` manually, even with the
> merge driver.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. When I meet a confliction, I do resolved the package.json and then run `npm i --package-lock-only`, and the console do display a message saying that npm noticed the confliction and will try to resolve, then when the process ends, nothing more information displays and nothing happens. I also installed 'npm-merge-driver' but still no luck. I m using npm v6.14.15, hope someone can advice, thanks.

Comment: @WayneMao not sure how to advise, maybe a later npm?

I want to add that npm-merge-driver is now archived.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'm using:

```sh
# Change to upstream lock file
git checkout origin/branch-you-are-merging-with package-lock.json
npm i
```

This will force you to have all the upstream versions and only then add your new dependencies to lock-file by using `npm i`

Comment: You don't need to checkout the file from the upstream branch. Npm will detect the lock file is conflicting and try to auto merge

Comment: @Vinz243 Exactly, it works most of the time. I really _shouldn't_ have to checkout the file. :)